# Applying labelling with obstacles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling, expression, point-in-polygon

I'm working with QGIS 3.16 Hannover and I'm quite confused with the option `Features act as obstacles`.

According to QGIS documentation ([13. The Style Library » 13.3. Setting a label » 13.3.2.3.4.4. Obstacles](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/label_settings.html#obstacles))

> an obstacle is a feature over which QGIS avoids placing other
> features’ labels or diagrams.

However, this option can only be activated if the labels for that layer are already active.

I've got a polygon layer (in blue in the example below) which I want to label (Sevilla); and a point layer (in red in the example) which I'm not labelling. What I want is that the red dots act as obstacles, so the label of the blue polygon was automatically displaced to where it doesn't interfere with them.

[image]

How should it be done?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Why obstacles do not work**

The setting `Features act as obstacles` only works for features of the same layer.

**Use Geometry generator to define label placement**

Go to `Label / Placement tab` and use Geometry generator to define the area inside the polygon where the label is allowed to be placed. Use an expression that *excludes* the area around the points: create a buffer around the points and subtract that area from the polygon you want to label.

**Screenshot:**

*Area hached in dark blue is the area created by the geometry generator: the area where label placement is allowed:*
[image]

**How to create the area where the label is allowed**

To get the point geometries from the layer `point` on your polygon layer, use `aggregate('point', 'collect', $geometry)`, create a buffer around `$geometry` and merge (dissolve) the single buffers creating again a buffer around the result with distance of 0. Then use `difference` to subtract this from your polygon geometries (`$geometry`). The whole expression looks like (replace `5000` on line 7 with a buffer size that fits your needs):

```
difference (
    $geometry,
    buffer (
        aggregate( 
            'point', 
            'collect', 
            buffer ($geometry,5000)
        ),
        0
))
```

*For better results, you can try setting placement mode to `Horizontal` (instead of `Around Centroid`) - this is especially useful with many "forbidden" areas where only small areas left for the label to be placed:*

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that this method will consume a lot of computer resources. Because the buffer of all points will be calculated for each label.

Comment: @Babel: That's a truely beautiful solution. But I think your statement that `Features act as obstacles` only works for features of the same layer is incorrect. Please see my answer and demo here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/470362/overlapping-labels .

Comment: @peter thanks for clarification! Label placement/obstacle settings are indeed not the most intuitive to understand.

Answer (score 5):

Just assign any labels to your points. After that, the circle label will bypass the points. You can then make the point labels completely transparent.[image]

Comment: Fast and efficient!