# Overlapping labels

Tags: qgis

I have a problem with overlapping labels from layer X to layer Y area. I want to automate my work and I'm looking for a tool to help me set the location of the label outside of layer Y (that grayed out area in the image), or to minimise as much as possible the occurrence of labels over the layer area.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: See this alternative answer, where one removes the conflicting areas from the suitable ones: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/415805/features-act-as-obstacles-in-qgis

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can discourage the placement of labels over your features.

In **Layer properties**|**Labels**|**Placement** scroll way down to **Obstacles**.

There, check the checkbox to make features act as obstacles.

On the right you will find a button **Settings**. In the dialog it shows you can change how much the features on this layer will
object against labels being placed upon their interior or boundary.

Now, when labels on the other layers are placed in a fixed spot, like with `offset from centroid` or `around centroid` turning this option on will simply stop them from being shown. To allow these labels to move to a free spot, you need to set the placement mode for labels on the other layers to `free`.

[image: Features act as obstacles demo]